# what does the format %c%.8x mean in snprintf

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

In the code below, what does `%c%.8x` format mean?

If for example `val` had the value 8 what is being put in 'buf'?

```
int send_cmd(int fd, char cmd, int val) {
char buf[32];
int res;
  snprintf(buf,32,"%c%.8x\n",cmd,val);
  res = write (fd, buf, 10); // send X00000000<LF>
  if (res == 10) 
    return 0;
  else {
    fprintf(stderr,"Did not send ten -> %d\n",res);
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: That is *two* format specifiers: `"%c"` and `"%.8x"`. As for what each mean I suggest [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, let me tell you, `%c%.8x` are two different format specifiers, `%c` and `%.8x`.

That said,

- `%c` is much familier, prints the character representation of the supplied `int` argument.
- Regarding the less familiar `%.8x` format specifier, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1/p4, for the *precision* option, (*emphasis mine*)

  > Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`. After the `%`, the following
  >   appear in sequence:
  >
  > - An *optional* precision that gives the **minimum number of digits to appear** for the `d`, `i`,
  >     `o`, `u`, `x`, and `X` conversions, the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point
  >     character for `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, and `F` conversions, [...] The precision takes the form of a period (`.`) followed either by an
  >     asterisk `*` (described later) or by an optional decimal integer; [...]